# giving a number for each cell in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I wrote a code that gives each cell in my TableView a number starting from 8 and when it reach 12 the counter which I called it in app hours

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

while (hour < 15)
{
    if (hour == 12) {
        hour=1;
    } else {
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",hour];
        cell.textLabel.text = [courses objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = str;
        NSLog(@"%@",str);
        hour++;
        return cell;

    }
}

return cell;}
```

That worked fine when I run the app with simulator but when I scroll it keeps changing the number in the first and second cell and I want the numbers to not change even if I scrolled the table .

how I can do that ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: oh snap, nevermind what i said xD

Comment: that's what I get for not reading the code right

Comment: add this code after UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];///
    if(cell == nil) {
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero 
  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `hour` is defined outside of the method and is not linked to the cell's `indexPath`. If you want to ensure that the displayed string remains constant for a cell, you should probably be able to compute it deterministically from the `indexPath` alone, thus even if the table loads the cells out of order, they will maintain their correct text.

Comment: how I can do that ? I sorry but I'm a beginner here

Comment: It really depends what defines how your cells should display the numbers? Should cell #1 display `1`, #2 `2` and so on? If so, set hour to be `indexpath.row`. What is the pattern you want to display?